# Which are tangents

Tags: functions

[image]

We are asked to see which are tangents and which aren't. I think B3, bottom left and bottom middle are not tangents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **tangent** to a **curve** is a **straight line** that **just touches** the curve, such that the **slope** of the tangent is exactly that as the slope of the curve. By that definition, all except for B5 display tangents.

EDIT: The picture is unclear, so it is difficult for me to tell in the cases of B3 and B4. A larger picture would help, or you could judge this yourself using the definition I provided above.

Comment: What do you mean by "just touches" ?

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @J.W.Perry The cusp at B5 is non-differentiable, so it doesn't have a defined tangent. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: @DBF There's a point $(x1,y1)$ on the curve which is also on the tangent line.

Comment: @DBF I forgot to mention: at that point (x1,y1) the tangent and the curve must have the same gradient. You can verify this by differentiating the curve at that point.

Answer (score 2):

B1 and B2 are clearly expressing the unique tangent lines at $x=0$ in your image.

There are infinitely many lines "touching" at $x=0$ on B5, but no unique defined tangent line.

B6 is clearly expressing the unique tangent line at $x=0$.

There are definitely no tangent lines being expressed in B3.

In B4 one is definitely not the tangent line, but the other does appear to be the tangent line at $x=0$ (I cannot see the names of the two lines but I think it says $c_2$).

We define the tangent line to a curve $f(x)$ at a point $P(x_0,f(x_0))$ as being the unique line through $P$ with slope 
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}.$$
If this slope does not exist, then there is no tangent line at $P$.

Comment: You might want to clarify that a tangent is necessarily unique.  It seems implied, but a lot of people don't understand this very basic concept (during senior year of high school, I would draw graphs like B3 in an attempt to prove my calculus teacher wrong).